# Second monitor not being detected on Ubuntu 16.04 / XCFE desktop

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, amd-graphics

I'm using an AMD RX 470 graphics card and when I connect two monitors to it (one using HDMI the other with DVI) it will display the same image on both monitors. I've tried install 'amdgpu-pro' package following the instructions on the AMD site, but I always get a 'Low graphics mode' error when booting up, and I'm forced to uninstall it to return to regular booting. When I'm in the 'Display' setting, it shows only one monitor 'default' and it only shows one value for all options (resolution is stuck at 1920x1080, refresh rate is stuck at 77.0, etc.). Clicking 'Identify Displays' shows 'Dispaly: default' at the bottom of both monitors (they're still being mirrored).

What's the way to get dual monitor working in my environment?

xrandr:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm 1920x1080     77.00*
```

sudo lshw -C display:

```
  *-display UNCLAIMED     
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
   vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: cf
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d01fffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:dfe00000-dfe3ffff memory:dfe40000-dfe5ffff
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the GUI named arandr. Helps with xrandr under hood.  I have had fabulous experience with it. It handles problem of listing devices and you pull down menus to activate devices.

Without that, first step is show us "xrandr -q" output. Need to be sure hardware is detected. Then worry about if it is xrandr compatible. Not all video cards are.

What is the video card? If you have Nvidia, there is separate layer of questions.